# JavaScript Module assignment pattern

Tags: javascript

I am reading [A JavaScript Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/), and wondering why bother to do the module assignment by firing an immediate anonymous function call like this:

```
YAHOO.myProject.myModule = function () {

    return  {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.",
        myPublicMethod: function () {
            YAHOO.log("I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.");
        }
    };

}();
```

**instead of directly assign the object to `YAHOO.myProject.myModule` like this:**

```
YAHOO.myProject.myModule = {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.",
        myPublicMethod: function () {
            YAHOO.log("I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.");
        }
    };
```

Comment: in this case - is a same

Answer (score 2):

In that example, there isn't any point. You didn't read enough of the document you linked to.

Section 3 is *Add "private" methods and variables in the anonymous function prior to the return statement.*, and that demonstrates why you would want to use an IEFF here.

It is so you can define local variables which are accessible to the functions you are making public, but aren't directly accessible themselves.